# Select ul element with same class inside ul element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How select second ul element with "dropdown-menu" class inside ul element with same class?

```
<ul class=" dropdown-menu">
<li>
<ul class=" dropdown-menu">
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `ul.dropdown-menu ul.dropdown-menu` select with CSS or JS?

Comment: .dropdown-menu li > .dropdown-menu

Comment: It does not matter

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select just the 2nd element, here is the workaround:

#### CSS

```
.dropdown-menu .dropdown-menu:first-child {}
```

More specific version:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li ul.dropdown-menu:first-child {}
```

#### jQuery

```
$('.dropdown').find('.dropdown:first').addClass('child-dropdown-menu');
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure js answer
I'm assuming you already have the ul reference in a variable.

```
var uls = ul.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var targetUl = undefined;

for(var i = 0; i < uls.length; i++){
    for( var j = 0; j < uls[i].classList.length; j++){
        if(uls[i].classList[j] == "dropdown-menu"){
            targetUl = uls[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```